# modify uniform value in opengl shader builder

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I'm using apple's opengl shader builder to learn GLSL.

And the problem I'm having is that I do not understand how to modify the uniform I defined in a frag shader.

[image]

As you can see I have a uniform variable named "someValue" with type GL_INT.

And in the Symbols view it shows three blank field for me to filled out.

The variable I defined is in GL_INT type so which blank should I use anyway and why is there 3 blank fields ?

And for the uniform "tex":

[image]

say I have 3 texture in slot 0 ~ 2.

What should I fill in the 3 blank fields to change the texture I want to use ? (I tried some combination and it seems only the second blank will do the work -- eg. fill in 1 for GL_TEXTURE1)

Comment: If you [read the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGLShaderBuilderUserGuide/Tasks/Tasks.html) there's a section titled "Modifying Uniform Variables" that explains it.

Comment: Actually, looking more closely, it doesn't explain much. I'd file a Radar on that.

Answer (score 0):

It is explained in the "Modifying Uniform Variables" section of this article: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGLShaderBuilderUserGuide/Tasks/Tasks.html

In the section on the bottom, the controls are shown for whichever `uniform` that you have selected on the top.

Some `Uniform` variables have more than one value (for example, a `vec3` has `vec3.r` `vec3.g` `vec3.b` (which can also be referenced as `x,y,z`)), and there will be a separate controller for each value in the `uniform` variable.

Now, Apple wants you to play around with your shaders a little bit, so they've given you the ability to write in three potential numbers for each value in a uniform.  The idea is that you put in some numbers and then use the slider below to "morph" between those numbers, and then see what happens inside of your shader as a result.

In the case of a texture, you will probably want to set all three fields to the same value.